# How do you create a for loop with a dynamic range?

Tags: python

I am iterating through a list.  An element could be added to this list during an iteration.  So the problem is that the loop only iterates through the original length of this list.

My code:

```
    i = 1
    for p in srcPts[1:]:  # skip the first item.
        pt1 = srcPts[i - 1]["Point"]
        pt2 = p["Point"]

        d = MathUtils.distance(pt1, pt2)
        if (D + d) >= I:
            qx = pt1.X + ((I - D) / d) * (pt2.X - pt1.X)
            qy = pt1.Y + ((I - D) / d) * (pt2.Y - pt1.Y)
            q  = Point(float(qx), float(qy))
            # Append new point q.
            dstPts.append(q)
            # Insert 'q' at position i in points s.t. 'q' will be the next i.
            srcPts.insert(i, {"Point": q})
            D = 0.0
        else:
            D += d
        i += 1
```

I've tried using `for i in range(1, len(srcPts)):` but again the range stays the same even after more items have been added to the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `len(srcPts)` is only computed once, when you pass it as an argument to the `range` generator.  So you need to have a terminating condition that repeatedly evaluates the current length of `srcPts` during each iteration.  There's many ways to do this, such as :

```
while i < len(srcPts):


  ....
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm such a Python noob.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use a `while` loop instead in this case:

```
i = 1
while i < len(srcPts):
    # ...
    i += 1
```

A `for` loop creates an iterator for your list, *once*. And once created that iterator does not know that you altered the list in the loop. The `while` variant shown here *recalculates* the length each time instead.

Comment: Well, that's not true. Python allows you to change list you're iterating over. In fact, when you append to a list it will scan through this added element; the same for inserting elements. To make a copy of your list for iterating over it you can write `for i in lst[:]:` or do other tricks. More on this [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: @SergeyIvanov: I didn't say Python doesn't allow you to, I said the `for` loop doesn't know the list was altered. Note that the OP *already used slicing* here. He is looping over a partial copy (all but the 1st element).

Comment: @SergeyIvanov: And that is the point here; the OP *wants the loop to include the added elements*, inserted in the loop body.

Comment: I see. I point out that _for_ loop knows that you changed iterator/list when you don't create a copy and thus can iterate over those new added elements. When you do slicing however, you create a copy and cannot iterate over new elements.

Answer (score 2):

In the line:

```
for p in srcPts[1:]:  # skip the first item.
```

slicing makes a new copy of scrPtrs, so it is fixed size.

Disclaimer: It feels wrong to modify a list being iterator over, yet this works...

Create an iterator over the list prevents the copy and still allows items to be added and inserted:

```
L = [1,2,2,3,4,5,2,2,6]
it = iter(L)
next(it) # skip the first item
for i,p in enumerate(it,1):
    if p == 2:
        L.insert(i+1,7) # insert a 7 as the next item after each 2
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
2
7
2
7
3
4
5
2
7
2
7
6
```