# Iterate and delete the files in a directory

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to iterate over a few files from a directory , then I am copying them in a group(based on  their initial name) to a particular location and then deleting them from the current direcory . But since I delete them after grouping them together , I get a file not found exception when the loop move over to the next file which is deleted . How can I resolve it : 
Here is my code:

```
import os
import csv
import glob,fnmatch, shutil ,time

ftp_directory = 'C:\\CIRP\\Velocidata\\Test\\'
IFIND_LOCATION = 'C:\\CIRP\\Velocidata\\Test2\\'

# Getting the list of all files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ftp_directory):
    # Filtering for group names that are 'Inprogress'
    groups_beingworked = []
    for name in files:
      #Getting the exception in the below line in the second iteration 
      group = name[0:name.lower().find('infile')]
      for loop2 in files:
       if (loop2[:len(group)].lower() == group):
         groups_beingworked.append(loop2)
       for loop3 in groups_beingworked:
              shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root,loop3) ,IFIND_LOCATION)
              print ('Deleting the file : ' + loop3)
              #File removed from the FTP location through a ftp conn created elsewhere
              ftpconn.delete(os.path.join(root, loop3))
```

List of sample files I am trying to go through is :

```
file1.new.infile.type1
file1.new.infile.type1
file2.old.infile.type2
file1.new.infile.type1
file2.old.infile.type2
file3.rec.infile.type3
```

Comment: Can't you just do the copy and delete loop part of the program after finishing looping over the whole directory since you saved the the files you want to process in a list anyway? Maybe also possible to not "clean" the list and do write all absolute paths in the list and then delete it? ----
Sorry could not comment, since I had not enough reputation

Comment: I can not complete the whole loop without processing it , as there are multiple groups within one list of files . I want to copy and remove the group as soon as I identify it . Is there any way I can clean and update the list in for loop each time I delete as you mentioned ?

Comment: maybe this question helps you a little: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725458/how-do-you-create-a-for-loop-with-a-dynamic-range)

Comment: Can you give me a littile more help by giving me some code snippet applicable here . I am trying to wrap my head around the link that you posted above , but I am dragging myself into more complexities.

Comment: Maybe you could try walking the directories in bottom up manner. That way the subdirectories and files are processed first. Therfore set the topdown parameter to False. e.g. `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown=False)`